# MySql join three tables together and counting row

Tags: mysql

Join three tables and count

Table Ministry

```
mid  m_name
1    Health
2    Telecom
3    Economic
```

Table DocumentDetail

```
id  m_id doc_type 
1    3    1
2    1    2
3    2    3
4    3    2
5    2    4
6    3    1
```

Table Type:

```
dID   d_name
1     pdf
2     xls
3     doc
4     png
5     zip
```

I would like out put like this

```
m_name   pdf  xls  doc  png  zip
health   0    1    0    0    0
Telecom  0    0    1    1    0
Economic 2    1    0    0    0
```

can we query for output like this ? thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m_name,(SUM(CASE doc_type WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) as pdf,
      (SUM(CASE doc_type WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS xls,
      (SUM(CASE doc_type WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS doc,
      (SUM(CASE doc_type WHEN 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS png,
      (SUM(CASE doc_type WHEN 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS zip
FROM  Ministry INNER JOIN DocumentDetail ON Ministry.`mid` = DocumentDetail.`m_id`
GROUP BY m_name
```

Check here in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8a2b/2)
Hope this helps

Comment: This solution it would be work if data in table are fixed , but unfortunately my data in each table are dynamic

Comment: Have you figured out the solution?

Comment: Not yet, Maybe I have to try with PHP script to get the out put like this. I will try other solution if I got one, thank you for your time for take time with my question.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of `doc_type` is fixed, then you can try the following query else you may need to try dynamic sql query.

**Query**

```
select t1.m_name,
count(case t2.doc_type when 1 then 1 end) as pdf,
count(case t2.doc_type when 2 then 1 end) as xls,
count(case t2.doc_type when 3 then 1 end) as doc,
count(case t2.doc_type when 4 then 1 end) as png,
count(case t2.doc_type when 5 then 1 end) as zip
from Ministry t1
join DocumentDetail t2
on t1.mid = t2.m_id
group by t1.m_name;
```

Comment: No the doc_type is dynamic record, I just give example of the data to make u understand what I really want the output

Answer (score 0):

If the number of types will vary over time, use this solution:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      ', SUM(CASE dd.doc_type when ', dID,
      ' then 1 else 0 END) AS ', d_name, ' ')
  SEPARATOR '') INTO @sql
FROM Type;

SET @sql = CONCAT(
  'SELECT m.m_name', 
  @sql, 
  'FROM 
  Ministry AS m
  INNER JOIN DocumentDetail AS dd ON (m.mid = dd.m_id)
  GROUP BY m.m_name
  ORDER BY m.m_name'
);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Output:

```
m_name      pdf xls doc png zip
Economic    2   1   0   0   0
Health      0   1   0   0   0
Telecom     0   0   1   1   0
```

Comment: maybe I'm just start with query statement, by looking at ur query solution seem a bit complex for me, i don't understand.